# How do I make exceptions to Docker namespacing?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Via `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, I've configured a user namespace using `userns-remap`. I'm trying to start a `nginx-proxy` container, but it requires access to the Docker socket, which requires it to be *real* root. The namespacing breaks this, causing an `"operation not permitted"` error.

Is there a way to tell Docker to **not** put this one individual container in the namespace? If it's possible through docker-compose, that's preferrable.

Answer (score 6):

This problem can be solved by adding the command line option for the container in question `--userns=host`.

For `docker-compose`, the `version` must be `2.1` or [newer](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#userns_mode). You can add `userns_mode: 'host'` to the relevant service definition.